# Scanf and Printf in OpenMPI

Tags: c, openmpi

i am using ANSI C and OpenMPI library.

I have this code:

```
if(myRank == 0)
{
    printf("\n\tEnter bright: ");
    scanf("%d", &bright);
}
```

But when i run the program it first wait for key pressing (scanf) and then printf.
I really don't know what is happening.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps if it is first waiting for a key press _before_ it prints `"\n\tEnter bright: "`, then you have some other code that is calling another `scanf()`, or similar that requires input, and will block until it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has little to do specifically with MPI and is a pretty normal Unix I/O behaviour. The standard output stream is **line buffered**, which means that nothing is being sent to the underlying I/O subsystem unless a new line is encountered in the stream or a flush operation is enforced.

Compare the following: `printf("asdasd");` and `printf("asdasd\n");`. In the first case, `asdasd` is appended to the buffer of the `stdout` stream, but since there is no new line there, the buffer is not flushed and nothing is actually sent to the terminal. In the second case `asdasd` is appended to the output stream and then the presence of the new line results in an automatic flush, therefore `asdasd<new line>` is what you see immediately. As already shown by John Zwinck, `fflush(stdout);` can be used to forcefully flush the stream buffer.

Note that if you come from Windows backgroud, the standard output there is not line buffered and `printf("asdasd");` does result in `adsasd` being outputted without a following explicit flush operation. But then, even on Windows, it is possible that the I/O redirection mechanism of MPI is line buffered.

Answer (score 0):

I first wonder if it even makes sense to use scanf in such a way (there will be multiple processes involved--how do we know or assume that any of them will be attached to your terminal/keyboard?).  But anyway, try flushing after printing:

```
printf("\n\tEnter bright: ");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%d", &bright);
```

Comment: You're welcome.  If this answer solved your problem, please do accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: Most MPI implementations redirect the IO of `mpirun`/`mpiexec` to the standard input and output of rank 0, therefore `if (rank == 0) { scanf(); }` makes perfect sense. One catch is that this behaviour is not imposed by the standard and is therefore non-portable.